# Symfony2 Form collection handle request error "Neither the property nor one of the methods exist and have public access"

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, relationship, one-to-many

I have a problem when I want to handle form with collection

I have two entities FeatureCategory and Feature

User chooses one feature in every featureCategory (collection of featureCategories).

Feature category entity:

```
 class FeatureCategory
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Feature", mappedBy="featureCategory", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $features;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->features = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add feature
     *
     * @param \Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Feature $feature
     * @return FeatureCategory
     */
    public function addFeature(\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Feature $feature)
    {

        $feature->setFeatureCategory($this);
        $this->features[] = $feature;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove feature
     *
     * @param \Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Feature $feature
     */
    public function removeFeature(\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Feature $feature)
    {
        $this->features->removeElement($feature);
    }

    /**
     * Get features
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFeatures()
    {
        return $this->features;
    }
}
```

And feature entity:

```
class Feature
{
    /**
     * @var \Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory", inversedBy="features")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="feature_category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $featureCategory;

    /**
     * Set featureCategory
     *
     * @param \Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory $featureCategory
     * @return Feature
     */
    public function setFeatureCategory(\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory $featureCategory = null)
    {
        $this->featureCategory = $featureCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get featureCategory
     *
     * @return \Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory
     */
    public function getFeatureCategory()
    {
        return $this->featureCategory;
    }
}
```

Feature categories form:

```
class FeatureCategoriesFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('featureCategories', 'collection', array(
                'type' => 'site_frontend_feature_category',
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
            ->add('quantity', 'text', array(
                'data' => 1
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('feature_categories')
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'site_frontend_feature_categories';
    }
}
```

And feature category form:

```
class FeatureCategoryFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder)
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            /* Check we're looking at the right data/form */
            if ($data instanceof FeatureCategory)
            {
                $choices = $data->getFeatures();
                $form
                    ->add('features', 'entity', array(
                        'multiple'  => false,
                        'expanded'  => true,
                        'class' => 'SiteBackendBundle:Feature',
                        'property' => 'value',
                        'choices' => $choices,
                        'data' => null
                    ))
                    ->add('name', 'hidden', array(
                        'read_only' => true,
                        'label' => $data->getName()
                    ))
                ;
            }
        });

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory',
            'validation_groups' => array('feature_category')
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'site_frontend_feature_category';
    }
}
```

And finally my controller:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function addProductAction(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

        $item = $em->getRepository('SiteBackendBundle:Product')
            ->getItem($slug);

        if (!$item) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $featureCategories = $em->getRepository('SiteBackendBundle:FeatureCategory')
            ->getListByProduct($item);

        $featureCategoriesForm = $this->createForm('site_frontend_feature_categories', array('featureCategories' => $featureCategories),
            array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_order_add_product', array(
                    'slug' => $item->getSlug(),
                ))
            )
        );

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
                $featureCategoriesForm->handleRequest($request);

                if ($featureCategoriesForm->isValid()) {
                    //order add product logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After `$featureCategoriesForm->handleRequest($request);` line, I got an error

> Neither the property "features" nor one of the methods
>   "addFeatur()"/"removeFeatur()", "addFeature()"/"removeFeature()",
>   "setFeatures()", "features()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have
>   public access in class "Site\BackendBundle\Entity\FeatureCategory".

Sorry for this long post
Could anyone help?

Comment: Missing FeatureCategory::setFeatures()

Comment: In form I use by_reference => false, so for setting data should be used add/remove methods instead of setFeatures

Comment: You haven't set `allow_add` and `allow_delete` in your `FeatureCategoriesFormType`. If you have a look at the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) you'll see the default values for those options are `false`.  That might be the cause?

Comment: You are right about allow_add and allow_delete, but I don't use these options at all. For example, in form I have feature category "color" and features "white", "grey", "yellow" etc. And user chooses one of them, he cannot add new or remove old features, just chooses from list

Comment: which version of the framework are you using? there is an open issue about something similar on the 2.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833637/form-collectiontype-with-radio-buttons-fails-after-symfony-2-7-upgrade

Comment: What if you change the method name addFeature to addFeatur (without e) and also with removeFeatur(e) ?

Comment: Symfony 2.6.11 @Matteo

Comment: I've tried it before published this post, and unfortunately nothing changed @Frankbeen

Comment: I updated project to Symfony 2.7.3, problem is somewhere in my app :) @Matteo

Comment: I had written setter before, just for testing, and in $features collection was only one checked object Feature without array. And after flush error occurred "Features must be array, but object given" @Cerad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593677/sf2-form-error-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I fixed issue using entities as arrays with `choice` type form, without `data_class` and so on